# Is it possible to group by an expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

In SQL Server 2008 is it possible to derive a column from a boolean expression like the one below?

```
SELECT item
     , (SUM(dqty) =pty) as tORf
GROUP BY item WHERE uid = 1
```

Comment: You need a `FROM` in your select for starters.

Comment: Did you try it? I'm getting an `incorrect syntax near '='`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your proposed syntax even means or what results you would expect to achieve.

Comment: If you intended to compare the sum against `pty`, then you query does not make much sense, since `pty` does not appear in `GROUP BY` and is not wrapped in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but not directly like that. You can use the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT item, (CASE WHEN SUM(dqty) = pty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tORf
FROM your_table
GROUP BY item, pty
WHERE uid = 1
```

Note: I added the missing `FROM` statement and also added `pty` to the `GROUP BY`. If you don't want to group by it, then you need to use it in an aggregate function. It cannot stay loose like in your query.

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/773059/957150/).

Answer (score 2):

Your current syntax is invalid and won't work.  However, you *can* use equals to define an alias as follows:

```
SELECT
    item,
    pty = SUM(dqty)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY item;
```

### Demo

But the following would fail:

```
SELECT item, SUM(duty) = pty FROM yourTable ...
```

In other words, the alias needs to appear on the LHS.